# what is the meaning of navigator.userAgent.indexOf in javascript,i used this in my javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this for my browser width checking..

But i dont know the exact meaning,i'm new to javascript.

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
 if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("840") != -1){

 //

 }
```

Comment: It certainly doesn't check the width of anything.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first you have your `navigator`-Object which contains information about the browser (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp)). Secondy you have the `userAgent`-Property of your `navigator`-Object which "Returns the [user-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header sent by the browser to the server"

Then you use the string returned by the `userAgent`-Property and call the function `indexOf`. This functions "returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string." (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)). This means it will return `-1` if the string was not found.

But the problem you are facing is, that you cannot check the width of the browser window this way. You can only identify if the user has a Firefox etc. Thefore you should use property like `window.innerWidth` etc.

Answer (score 1):

navigator.userAgent will return a string. Using the indexOf() function, you can get the index of a character or a string in the navigator.userAgent string. All strings in JavaScript have the function indexOf().

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.userAgent` contains info about the user's browser.

`.indexOf("something")` will return the index of the word "something".

For example:

```
"ABC".indexOf("B"); // will return 1 as indexes start from 0. Will return -1 if the word is not found
```

For your requirement, you'll have to use:

```
window.innerWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

condition to check if browser's userAgent containg information about screen resolution, but I am not shure, because my Opera didnt contain such information in navigator.userAgent, often to get screen resolutions people using window.outerWidth variable

Answer (score 0):

In provided snippet you check whether string representing your browser has a substring "840". In case string has provided substring `indexOf(...)` will return first index of the substring in the string (`navigator.userAgent`), otherwise it will return `-1`.

Here are some links to documentation that may be useful to understand your condition statement:

1. [navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.navigator) - `Navigator` object, which can be queried for information about the application running the script.
2. [userAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.userAgent) - user agent string for the current browser.
3. [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) - index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value.

Common `userAgent` string may look as follows:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36

As you can see, it does not contain information regarding browser width. In order to get browser width and check for example that it is less or equal to "840" pixels, you can do the following:

```
if(window.innerWidth <= 840) {
  // Do something
}
```

If you want to watch changes of your browser width, you can subscribe to `resize` event:

```
window.onresize = function() {
  if(window.innerWidth <= 840) {
    // Do something
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }
}
```